# Job con tiempo de ejecuciòn dinamico

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

Quisiera ver si me pudieran ayudar, tengo que crear un job, pero que el tiempo que se ejecute lo obtenga de una tabla de base de datos, es decir si en el valor buscado se tiene un 10, se corra cada 10 minutos, es decir, que tome ese numero conforme se cambie en la base de datos.

Gracias.

Comment: El job lo quieres crear en el sistema operativo, en una base de datos o dónde? Si es en una base de datos, en cuál? Cuál es la estructura de la tabla con el tiempo que buscas? Intentaste algo? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Gracias por tu retroalimentación, es en una base de datos de SQL Server, y la tabla es una de configuración, y de ahi tomo el valor.
Hice una prueba, que por medio del script se traiga ese dato a traves de la consulta SQL, pero no me lo refleja.

Comment: El job como piensas implementarlo, toda la informacion agregala tu pregunta

Comment: Claro que sí, les platico un poco mi trabajo, tengo un paquete en SSIS, el cual verifica una ruta que existan archivos modificados en los ultimas 2 horas, después de checar eso, es cuando entra en ejecución el JOB, que se estaría ejecutando cada cierto tiempo para ver si hay modificaciones en la ruta mencionada, y en caso de que no haya modificaciones se envía un correo.

Comment: Revisa los enlaces que te indiqué. No hay mejor forma de contarnos cosas que mostrando el código (editando la pregunta usando el enlace 'editar' que hay justo debajo). Revisa la respuesta de Luis, puede que sea la correcta!

Comment: claro que si amigos, contemplare todo eso!

Answer (score 2):

Todos los jobs tienen asignado un horario que existe en `msdb.dbo.sysschedules`. No necesitas tener una tabla adicional para manejar los horarios. Para actualizar esta vista del sistema, se usa `sp_update_schedule`.

Así, podrías actualizar la frecuencia usando algo así:

```
EXEC sp_update_schedule 
               @name = N'Nombre del Horario', 
               @freq_subday_type = 0x4, --Para definir minutos
               @freq_subday_interval = 10;
```

Más información, la puedes conseguir en [la ayuda del procedimiento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-schedule-transact-sql) para conocer otras opciones.

Comment: Como comenta Luis Cazares puedes actualizar el horario de ejecucion de tu Job, por lo que para ejecutar esa acualizacion necesitas un job que revise los cambios en tu tabla. mas info [aqui](https://www.sqlshack.com/generating-schedules-with-sql-server-agent/)

Comment: ok muchas gracias, revisare esa opción a detalle, que sera lo mas conveniente para hacerlo mas practico

Comment: No es necesario tener un job que revise los cambios en una tabla. Para eso existen los triggers que se ejecutan en cuanto hay cambios en la tabla. Pero como mencioné, no es necesario una tabla adicional porque la información está en las vistas del sistema.